# HTML5 / Android overlay on click

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-canvas

Well this is my first question here, so please forgive me if I`m doing it wrong.

I`m writing my first very simple HTML5 Mobile game and I have issue that on Android(maybe other phones also) there is yellow overlay when clicking on canvas(built-in browser).

On Opera Mobile 12 - there is light overlay.
On Firefox Nightly 18.01 - event not fired.

Here is the link on my prototype:
http://19th.tosteris.com/colo/

I searched and didn`t found anything useful.
Could someone tell me what the overlay is it, and why it didnt shows up here:
http://19th.tosteris.com/colo/2.html

Comment: I found the answer. When event attached to canvas, than Android displays this element overlay, like to show on which element you have clicked and when you attach event to window - there ne problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like it might be a default style issue where there are discrepancies between the default styles of activated elements in different browsers. To address this I always link a reset.css style sheet that wipes out all default style behaviors as my first css sheet.